# Как сохранить изменения в OllyDbg?

Tags: отладка

Ообственно сабж в заголовке, я уже читал, что надо кликнуть правой кнопкой - Copy to executable. Проблема в том, что дебаггер пытается сохранить какой-то совершенно посторонний `ntdll.dll`. Я вообще такой не открывал и не знаю что это, а тот файл, который был открыт, он не хочет сохранять. Что делать?

Comment: @Dark Byte, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделяете изменения и как сами же сказали выбираете ПКМ-Copy to executable.
Другое дело, что Вы возможно пишете в область виртуальной памяти, которой нет в оригинальном ехе. Посмотрите таблицу секций в ехе, особенно там где raw size != va size.